# Navigation set titleTextAttributes failed by swift3 , Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, attributes, uinavigationbar

I want my navigation title using TruncationMiddle like "ABC...XYZ" .
I try to do this, but I failed.
Thanks.

```
self.title = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
```

I got failed in my project
[Link of my project in GitHub.](http://github.com/Bruce9487/NavigationTitleQuestion1)

UPDATE IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: Show entire lines of code instead of just one two lines that YOU want others to see.

Comment: it's all my code to set navigation title. I don't know what you want to see.

Comment: The code you added is working fine for me. Can you please tell where in the controller have you added this code?

Comment: in viewdidload , I also update my project link in my question.

Comment: @PGDev Have any sample to me? Why you are working?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use `NSMutableParagraphStyle` instead of `NSParagraphStyle`.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
```

The `lineBreakMode` attribute then has a setter that you can use instead of setting the value directly with the key which is not allowed with the `NSParagraphStyle` class and the `truncationMode` key.

Comment: "NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle" get error like "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSAttributedStringKey' "

Comment: Keep on using `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`, `NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle` is for the IOS 11 API.

Comment: I also try to do this function but it seems not work.

Comment: How to do this? I use guard  navigationController != nil ,and It's not work too.

Comment: I got failed in my project. https://github.com/Bruce9487/NavigationTitleQuestion1

Comment: Just loading that project as it is worked on my machine

Comment: What's wrong with my situation? I call your function in viewDidLoad, but it also failed. What things do I miss to think?

Comment: Since you said you were not using storyboards I'm assuming you did not embed your view controller inside a UINavigationController.

Comment: But my sample project like question link using the storyboard also have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Custom Label in Navigation bar.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:50))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.lineBreakMode = .truncateMiddle

self.navigationItem.titleView = label 

// OR 

// self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem.titleView =  label
```

You can also show multiline in label if you want then just set `numberOfLines` to `0` and linebreak mode to worldwrap  :)

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following line into your code:

```
    self.title = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    let navLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
    navLabel.text = self.title
    navLabel.textColor = .white
    navLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14.0)
    navLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    navLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    navLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel
```